# Derivation of properties of Regular open sets.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I've been stuck on this question for quite a while and I would appreciate if someone could help me out. 
A is regular open iff $A=A^{{\bot\bot}}$ where $A^{\bot}$ = X - $\overline{A}$.

$A^{\bot} = int(A^{c})$ and $A^{{\bot\bot}} = A = X - \overline{int(A^{c})}$ 
I don't know how to continue from here, in particular how does this imply A is regular open .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is a regular set, let's show that $A^{\bot\bot}=A$.

$ A\subset \bar A$ implies that $X-\bar A\subset X-A$ since $A$ is open, $X-A$ is closed, we deduce that $\overline{X-\bar A}\subset X-A$. Let $x\in X-A$, suppose that $x$ is not in $\overline{X-\bar A}$, this implies that $x$ is in $int(\bar A)=A$ since $A$ is regular contradiction. We deduce that $X-A=\overline{X-\bar A}$. This is equivalent to saying that $A=X-(X-A)=X-\overline{X-\bar A}=A^{\bot\bot}$.

Conversely, suppose that $A^{\bot\bot}=A$, $X-\overline{X-\bar A}=A$ this implies that $X-A=\overline{X-\bar A}$, $A\subset \bar A$ implies that $int(A)\subset in(\bar A)$, we have to show that $int(\bar A)\subset A$. Let $x\in int(\bar A)$, if $x$ is not in $A$, $x\in X-A=\overline{X-\bar A}$. This implies that the intersection of every open subset containing $x$ and $X-\bar A$ is not empty, in particular $int(\bar A)\cap (X-\bar A)$ is not empty. Contradiction.